# PHP script stops occasionally after fsockopen line

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

I have an IPN listener script in PHP. Most of the time it works. Just a few times a year, the script stops after this line:

```
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://'.$server, 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

There is an if else like this after the above line:

```
if (!$fp) {
  // Process error. Log entries for failure.
} else{
  // Process success. Log entries for success.
}
```

Neither of the above log entries are made. So I think the script stopped working.

I was not able to simulate or reproduce this on localhost. So I don't know what causes this issue or how to fix it.

php.ini has max_execution_time > 30, so the script is not stopped by the server. The site is not very busy, may be 20-30 transactions a day.

Any suggestions on where or what to look for?

Thank you.

Comment: There is a chance php process just crashed. I also have some sporadic crashes with the code that deals with network sockets.

Comment: Any idea how to at least detect such a crash?

Comment: Just make sure whatever starts the php process - captures its stderr + stdout somewhere

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache. How do I know what is starting the php process?